# How to update parent's state on each child mount, not after all children are mounted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update parent element's state from within child elements.

I want the update to happen immediately after each child element mounts, therefore I am using `useEffect` hook and calling the update function `setData` (passed down from parent) from there.

It seems, however, that each subsequently mounted child element that gets mounted is oblivious of the changes to the data made by the previously mounted child element. That is, it operates on an empty `data` array, whereas for the second, third and fourth element the array should not be empty anymore.

I believe this is because `setData` is scheduled for execution only after all of the elements mount. Is this correct? If so, how can I work around this?

```js
 function Parent() {
            
            const [data, setData] = React.useState([])
                          
            function changeData(index, value) {
                logData()
                let new_data = Array.from(data)
                new_data[index] = value
                setData(new_data)
            }
            
            function logData() {
                console.log(data)
            }
            
            let children = Array(4).fill(null).map((item, index) => {
                return <Child id={index} changeData={changeData} />
            })
            
            return (
                <div>
                    {children}
                    <button onClick={logData}>Log data</button>
                </div>
            )
        }

  function Child(props) {

      const ref = React.useRef(null)

      React.useEffect(() => {
          props.changeData(ref.current.id, ref.current.id)
      }, [])

      function onClickHandler(e) {
          let element_id = e.target.id
          props.changeData(element_id, element_id)
      }

      return (
          <button ref={ref} id={props.id} onClick={onClickHandler}>Child</button>
      )
  }

  ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <head>
                <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@^16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
            </head>
            <div id="root"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: React batches state updates that happen inside of `useEffect` and as you are rendering all the children at once all the effects will be called at once. Your children shouldn't need to rely on state updates triggered by siblings.

Comment: You could try using forceUpdate(). Found this for emulating useForceUpdate: https://sung.codes/blog/2018/11/08/emulate-forceupdate-with-react-hooks/. However you can fall back to mutable data: `let mutableData=[]`; `<Child id={index} changeData={changeData} data={mutableData} />`; `props.mutableData[index] = value; props.changeData( mutableData )`

Comment: Also your `changeData` function doesn't use the current state to update the state. This will lead to updates happening in batch overriding each other. You need to use the callback version of `setState`.

Comment: What is the original problem you are trying to solve with that? There is likely a better approach to it that doesn't require your children to be aware of state updates made by other mounting siblings.

Comment: @trixn: Thanks for the input, helpful. The original problem is: I have 4 dropdowns, each allowing to select a sound's name. I am tracking the selected sounds (audio buffers) in a separate array, based on dropdown values. However, on first render of the app, when there are no user interactions yet and I am just grabbing input from the default dropdown selections, the sounds array will always have only 1 element, as each dropdown's useEffect operates on the original, empty array.

Comment: @barciewicz I'm not sure if I fully understand that. All of these dropdowns are displaying the same list of sound names to select from? Why is this list not known beforehand and you simply pass the choices and the default selected item as props? Also you can init your state already with the default choices and pass those as the selected values into your respective dropdowns.

Comment: I created a sandbox with a possible solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-brown-jo1yh?file=/src/App.js . Does that meet your requirements?

Comment: @trixn: Many thanks! I adapted your solution and indeed, getting rid of the useEffect in child elements and hardcoding the initial dropdowns values instead seem to work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When updating state based on the current state you should always use the callback version of `setState`. See [Why is setState giving me the wrong value](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value) for details.

If you do not use the callback version successive calls to `setState` that rely on the current state will override each other which may cause incorrect state if they are batched by react.

```
function changeData(index, value) {
    logData()
    setData(current => {
        // current is the current state including all previous calls to setState in this batch
        const new_data = Array.from(current);
        new_data[index] = value;
        return new_data;
    });
}
```

Updated example:

```js
function Parent() {
            
            const [data, setData] = React.useState([])
                          
            function changeData(index, value) {
                logData()
                setData(current => {
                  const new_data = Array.from(current);
                  new_data[index] = value;
                  return new_data;
                });
            }
            
            function logData() {
                console.log(data)
            }
            
            let children = Array(4).fill(null).map((item, index) => {
                return <Child id={index} changeData={changeData} />
            })
            
            return (
                <div>
                    {children}
                    <button onClick={logData}>Log data</button>
                </div>
            )
        }

  function Child(props) {

      const ref = React.useRef(null)

      React.useEffect(() => {
          props.changeData(ref.current.id, ref.current.id)
      }, [])

      function onClickHandler(e) {
          let element_id = e.target.id
          props.changeData(element_id, element_id)
      }

      return (
          <button ref={ref} id={props.id} onClick={onClickHandler}>Child</button>
      )
  }

  ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <head>
                <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@^16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
            </head>
            <div id="root"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**EDIT**: I created a sandbox with a possible solution, that does not require `useEffect` in your children:

[image: Edit silly-brown-jo1yh]

Please see if that works for you.

Comment: Hmm, I think it did not work. Please run the snippet and look and the output of `logData()` called on each child mount - it is still all empty arrays, not the data as adjusted by previous child mount.

Comment: @barciewicz You can't call anything in between renders of the children. Rendering in react is a single process where non of your code is executed in between. First it will render every single component that has updated and only after that any `useEffect` will be called. There is no "between each child mount". They mount all at once then all effects will be called. That is why on first mount they all see an empty state. I also added my possible solution to the answer. Feel free to accept it if it solved your problem.